# Object reference not set to an instance of an object... but with interfaces. (C#)

Tags: c#, interface, nullreferenceexception

The following two lines of code are causing an error in my program because of a NullReferenceException.

```
ISceneGraphFactory factory = null;
IGroupNode Root = factory.CreateGroupNode("Root", "GroupNode", null);
```

Both of these are interfaces.  So basically I am trying to create that second interface IGroupNode with the factory.  (The error occurs on the second line).  Here is how the interfaces themselves look:

```
public interface ISceneGraphFactory
{
    IDrawableNode CreateDrawableNode(string name, string DrawableType, object drawableData);
    IGroupNode CreateGroupNode(string name, string groupType, object groupData);
    IStateNode CreateStateNode(string name, string stateType, object stateData);
    ITransformNode CreateTransformNode(string name, string transformType, object transformData); 
}

public interface IGroupNode : ISceneNode, IEnumerable<ISceneNode>
{
    void AddChild(ISceneNode child);
}
```

They are both functioning and have worked in other programs.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error when working with interfaces?  I think it is complaining because I am using interfaces here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an object to call CreateGroupNode (since it is not static).

```
ISceneGraphFactory factory = null;
factory = new SomeClassThatImplementsISceneGraphFactory();
IGroupNode Root = factory.CreateGroupNode("Root", "GroupNode", null);
```

Some will point out not only is it not static it is "virtual" because it is only defined in an interface.  In any case you need an object to call it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is pretty clear here. You're assigning `null` to variable, and then try to do a method call on that. It can't work (unless the method is an extension method, but just assume it's not).

```
ISceneGraphFactory factory = null;
IGroupNode Root = factory.CreateGroupNode("Root", "GroupNode", null);
```

You have to assign an object to `factory` before calling any method. And because you're declaring variable using the interface, your object has to be an instance of a class which implements `ISceneGraphFactory`.

Comment: So could I potentially just create a dummy object and do it that way?  I don't need a factory object, I just need to make use of the methods linked with its interface.

Comment: Looks like you really don't get what interface is and how it works. No, you can't call a method of interface, because it has no code assigned (it's not implemented on interface level). You need a class which implements the interface (fulfill the contract), because that's what you're really calling here.

Comment: Yea that's what I meant by linked with it... I have the implementation of IFactory working, but it's implementation just returns other Interfaces anyway.

Comment: @DNA_Instant are you perhaps looking for a [static method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?